# Comparing values in grouped rows in R

Tags: r, time, rows, mean

I've already done some statistics but I'm completely new to R.
I have readings from several sensors that I want check. For this I'd like to compare for each sensor the mean in the previous and following 3 Minutes.
My data looks something like this:

```
 time   sensor  reading  
10:01        B     86.7  
10:01        A     87.6  
10:02        A     81.1  
10:02        B     32.1  
10:03        B     80.0  
10:03        A     20.8  
10:04        A     35.2  
10:04        B     10.0  
10:05        B     26.2  
10:05        A     59.0  
10:06        A     94.7  
10:06        B      6.8  
10:07        B     50.4  
10:07        A      5.0  
10:08        A     71.4  
10:08        B     83.5  
10:09        B     33.3  
10:09        A     82.5
```

For 10:05 the results should looks something like this:

```
 time   sensor  reading    mean
...
10:05        A     86.7    43.8  
10:05        B     87.6    51.36666667  
...
```

I know there is a way in SQL by joining the dataset with a grouped, filtered and then aggregated form of itself. But I try to avoid SQL here and tinkered with aggregate, subset and loop functions. But nothing seems to work.

I've googled the subject, but either I ask the wrong questions or there is no answer to be found. Or the matter is that simple, that I've missed an important lesson.

Comment: Please show the full expected output based on the example you provided.  You can check `rollmean` from `zoo`

Answer (score 1):

You can try following. I used only base R functions. Perhaps sometimes a little bit to complicated, but you will get some results. Hopefully the correct ones.

```
# change to time format
d$t <- as.POSIXct(d$time, format="%H:%M")
# function to add or substract 3 minutes
mns <- function(m) {
  x <- m * 60
  return(x)
}
# add columns with 3 minutes previous and after
d$tp <-    d$t - mns(3)
d$ta <-    d$t + mns(3)

# split the data according the sensors
d1 <- split(d, d$sensor)

# get the results per sensors and an interval of 6 minutes (before and after)
res <- lapply(d1, function(x){
  Mean=sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i, y){
  mean(y[ y$t[i] > y$tp & y$t[i] < y$ta, "reading"], na.rm = T)
  }, x)
  cbind.data.frame(time=x[, 1], Mean)
})
# convert to data.frame
do.call(cbind, res)
    A.time   A.Mean   B.time   B.Mean
1    10:01 63.16667    10:01 66.26667
2    10:02 56.17500    10:02 52.20000
3    10:03 56.74000    10:03 47.00000
4    10:04 58.16000    10:04 31.02000
5    10:05 42.94000    10:05 34.68000
6    10:06 53.06000    10:06 35.38000
7    10:07 62.52000    10:07 40.04000
8    10:08 63.40000    10:08 43.50000
9    10:09 52.96667    10:09 55.73333
```